# Why would the width of my site be different for www.domain.com and domain.com?

Tags: html, css, progressive-enhancement

If you open two versions of my site in two different tabs, go to [www.compversions.com](http://www.compversions.com) and [compversions.com](http://compversions.com), and also assuming that your resolution is at least 1680 x 1050, you will see the site rendered in two different sizes.

It was designed to be progressively enhanced, but what's the difference between 'www' and not having that on the domain that would make the site be different sizes on the exact same resolution monitor?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit1: The original problem is seen on Windows 7, Chrome latest build. I tested on a Mac in the latest Safari and it doesn't have that problem. But the Twitter counter and Google+ counter does show two different numbers.

This is the compversions.com screenshot - as you can see, everything is slightly bigger - especially the white middle part.

[image: compversions.com screenshot]

This is the www.compversions.com screenshot - this one is slightly smaller, especially the white middle part.

[image: www.compversions.com screenshot]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you mentioned on my 1680 x 1050 Macbook Pro running Safari. I also downloaded `http://compversions.com/imdex.html` and `http://www.compversions.com/imdex.html` on the command line with `curl` and verified that you're serving the _exact_ same file. No diffs. Same md5 sum.

Comment: @mu is too short - you are right, that's a tangential issue, but it's also something else that is kinda annoying.

Comment: @Asaph I updated the post with screenshots and specs of my system and browser. They are the EXACT same file, so that's why I am confused.

Comment: Add some other domain variations in hosts and see what's happening. The best way to find problem is setting http watch and compare streams for both cases, if streams content is identical then file a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've apparently accidently zoomed the non-www one in using for example Ctrl+Scrollwheel. Press Ctrl+0 to reset the zoom level. The browser remembers the zoom level for each host. This has nothing to do with HTML/CSS served by your site.

Comment: Oh wow! Brilliant. That worked. That's kinda INSANE!. Never even knew that happened. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, would a 301 redirect fix the Tweet and Google+ count button issues?

Comment: Definitely. It'll improve the SEO. Duplicate content is bad. Also, the `www` subdomain is soo 1990. Kill it.

Comment: Except that it has the higher counts for Google+ and Twitter button. If I do a permanent redirect will it get the higher number on compversions.com ?

Comment: No, the numbers won't be added up. Best what you can do is to contact Google+/Twitter support and ask them to merge the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a difference between them, but having the same page accessible through www or non-www can create duplicate content issues with search engines. You should probably redirect either your non-WWW to the WWW version or vice versa using a 301 redirect.

The immediate issue this is likely causing is your Google + and Tweet buttons show different counts for the two URLs, since they are counting them as two different pages.

If you're seeing them as different, you may just need to clear your browser cache. If you're still having the issue, looking at the pages on a different computer should show them as visually the same.

Comment: Updated my post with screenshots. The 301 redirect sounds like an interesting idea, will look into it.

Comment: So doing a 301 redirect will fix that Google+ and Tweet button problem?

Comment: Probably - a similar thing happens with Facebook Like ( yoast.com/facebook-like-duplicate-content). Not having that 301 may be costing you PageRank, as well, and affecting your search results. You might want also want to set a canonical tag in your HTML to be sure Google knows which is the right URL. Once you've done all that, probably get a Google Webmaster account if you haven't already and submit your preferred URL.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the subdomain "www" is pointing to a different folder on your server, they should be identical.

Comment: I agree. I am using Rails, and Heroku is doing the hosting. So no folders or manual pointing of anything on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked in Chrome version 13.0.782.112 beta and there is no difference between the sub domains. Also checked that the correct css files were downloaded, and there were no 404s.

Which browser are you seeing these results in?

Comment: Windows 7, Chrome 13.0.782.107 m.

I also updated the post to include screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...I see no difference in the dimensions of the two URL's, but what I do see is that the Tweet count and Publicity Meter counts vary between the two. Will continue to look into it.

Comment: That's probably because users are Tweeting some content at www. and some as non.www. A good reason to set up a 301 redirect from one to the other. A similar issue is described here: http://yoast.com/facebook-like-duplicate-content/